# Ems instead of px in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, units-of-measurement

I use `em`s everywhere in my style-sheets rather than `px`.  But the computed styles/metrics in Chrome Developer Tools seem to default to showing me `px`, even for elements where I've explicitly used `em`s in the style-sheet:

[image]

(This is a picture of the computed lengths for a button with an icon from Font Awesome.  I set the padding to 0.4em and I brought this up to see how tall the icon is.)  Sure I can just divide everything by 16, but for numbers like "14.841" that's not so easy to do in my head.  Is there a setting somewhere to change the length measurement unit?  (Kind of like in most desktop graphics and image manipulation programs where I can choose pixels, points, inches or centimeters?)  Either that, or is there somewhere else in the dev tools that can show the lengths in ems?  (The rulers, ...?)

Comment: Unfortunately for me I'm not familiar with how to change the units per say but I usually click the little arrows(e.g. in your picture where is says `-webkit-appearance:none`) and it shows the me numbers of that element. So if I used `padding:1em` when I click the little arrow, it would show me the padding-top, padding-bottom and etc in EM values as you requested.

Comment: "Sure I can just divide everything by 16"...yes but an em may not be 16px due to inheritance. In `rem` possibly, but even that is adjustable. It's more logical to use a fixed, known 'measure' of `px`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values shown on the Computed tab are just that: computed. Therefore, they are listed in a "absolute" length unit like pixels and not a "relative" length unit like ems, rems or percentage, which all base their size off of some other criteria. For instance, if you set an elment to 100% of the viewport width, it will show you how many pixels the width of the element computes to and there is no option to view the value in any other unit. Likewise, because you're using ems, how big your icon is will be based off the inherited font-size value.

In fact, I haven't tested this but I think the px values shown on the computed tab are technically shown in device pixels and not CSS pixels, as CSS pixels themselves are relative length units (since their size is based on the DPI of the device screen).

[Relative Length Units](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/syntax/units/rellength.htm)

[Absolute Length Units](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/syntax/units/abslength.htm)

Comment: They seem to be CSS pixels.  If I zoom to 175%, for example, the border (which is defined as 1px) is calculated as "0.571" units.  That's because at 175% zoom, 1 device pixel is .571 CSS pixels.  If I zoom to 200% then 1 device pixel is 0.5 CSS pixels, so the border will be 2 device pixels and the Computed tab shows me "1" (CSS pixel).  So the computed tab is showing a relative length unit, just the one that is least useful to me.

Comment: Ah, isn't that interesting... that would appear to be the case. Firefox and Safari also seem to behave the same way, showing px units for all computed lengths with no apparent way to see it in any other unit. I wonder why that is. Maybe submit a feature request?

Comment: Weirdly, you can choose which unit colors appear in (hex, rgb, hsl) but if you change the setting, only certain properties take on the new unit.